# How to update ACL for all S3 objects in a folder with AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

As part of an automated process in CodeBuild I want to update Access Control List for all files in a given folder (or more specifically all objects with given prefix). How to do it in a single line of bash code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following one liner works perfectly

> aws s3api list-objects --bucket $BUCKET_NAME$ --prefix $FOLDER_NAME$
>   --query "(Contents)[].[Key]" --output text | while read line ; do aws s3api put-object-acl --acl public-read --bucket $BUCKET_NAME$ --key
>   $line ; done

it's not formatted as code, so that it's readable without scrolling!

Comment: this requires me to press q each time a $line is used as it prints the (END) as output

Answer (score 2):

You can use **aws s3 cp**

```
aws s3 cp --grants foo=bar=baz s3://mybucket/mydir s3://mybucket/mydir
```

Reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Answer (score 0):

list all objects and modify acl by put-object-acl

```
acl=public-read

aws s3 ls s3://$bucket --recursive --endpoint-url=$endpoint | awk '{print $4}' > tos-objects.txt

cat tos-objects.txt | while read object
do
    echo -e "set acl of \033[31m $object \033[0m as $acl"
    aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket $bucket --key $object --acl $acl --endpoint-url=$endpoint
done
```